# Distribution for a sequence of events which the first one follows a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Imagine a simple website where a user can access and can click on a button that will refresh the page. On average, 50 000 requests are made to the webserver of this website in a month. We can assume that the number of number accesses to the website(the first request) in a month follows a Poisson distribution, but we know that, after accessing the page, on an interval of 20s, on average, the user will refresh the page 9 times(make 9 more requests). What would be the distribution of the request to the server in a range of a month then?

PS: One more piece of information: The website has a delay of 30ms to respond, so the user needs to wait at least 30ms to refresh the page.

It's a really interesting problem that came to my mind I dare say, basically a sequence of events in which the start follows a Poisson distribution, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Re the title: The Poisson is for event counts. Time is not a count. The body of the question doesn't seem to quite correspond to the title,  however.

Comment: That count *might*, or it might be close enough  for some purpose. Perhaps. But (random intervals of average 20sec)×(random number of intervals averaging 9) is assuredly not Poisson. It has units  for one thing

Comment: I'm not sure the edit fully resolves the issue, but its something of an improvement

Comment: I think this problem is indeterminate because the number of refreshes in the 20s can have any distribution. But I cannot think in a way to make the refreshes follow a distribution without having a user making overlapping refreshes.

Comment: If the number of refreshes followed a known distribution, a thing that could solve this problem is using the fact that: x=(1+r)*n, with x being the request in the month, r the refreshes, and n the initial request. So the number of requests would be a product of two random variables with known distributions. I don't know how to derive a distribution from this equation, but probably there is a known way of doing it.

Comment: It's not exactly a product; my very brief discussion above may have misled you (I was trying to convince you that time was not Poisson rather than present a clear and correct argument about what it would be). Imagine you have a Poisson number of refreshes and so a sum of inter-refresh times that are random. Then you have a sum of inter-event (time) random variables where the upper limit on the summation is itself Poisson (say). For the case where the count and durations are all mutually independent such distributions are well studied (it crops up a lot in actuarial literature ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... such as for  a random number of claims each with its own claim amount; so the distribution of aggregate losses is of that form), especially for the case of Poisson counts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution.  Of course, you might not have independence because things that impact responsiveness of a site - think times of heavier load for one example - will affect things like page refreshes across many people and within one person across time). You also must consider issues of heterogeneity of rates and times across people and within people across time.

Comment: The inter-refresh time is inherently positive (and you specified a minimum value for it), if you keep that in mind, I don't see how refresh times would overlap

Comment: Ok, solved then, thanks. Just write this as an answer so I can accept it as the right answer.